# Unable to see page content in Tab

Tags: facebook, tabs

I followed the instructions to create a tab using an URL with app ID and app URL so now I have the tab created, but it shows a blank page. I used Google sites to create the app- I created a three page "website". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This isn't really enough information to know what the problem is, did you use the correct URLs in the settings for your app on Facebook's side?

Comment: Yes, I used the correct URL. The title of the page shows at the top, which leads me to believe it is the correct URL. It is also exactly the same as the page URL.